# My image is not showing, could somebody help me out?

Tags: html, css, image

I have got this problem that my image is not showing, I used this code, and I hope someone can help me out (the weird names are dutch):

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Inloggen </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meetingchannel.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='inlogscherm'>
        <p class='welkomtekst'> Welkom </p>
        <div class='gegevens'>
            <form method='post' action='inloggen.php'>
                <input type='text' name='gebruikersnaam'><br />
                <input type='password' name='wachtwoord'><br />
                <input type='submit' value='Log in'><br />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class='achtergrondplaatje'>
        <img src='achtergrond.jpg'>
        <div class='logo'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can view the result here:

http://informatica.olvbreda.nl/5hGroepNikki/inloggen.html

Comment: Did you update your website? The source doesn't include the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is not included in your source `<img src='achtergrond.jpg'>`

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
`<img src='achtergrond.jpg'>'
```

to your page, and I saw the picture!